# Checking if a month and year in a date are in a sequence in list

Tags: c#, list

I have a C# `AxiomSubData` list with few columns and several number of rows of data for each column. One of the columns in the list is named as `Term` and it is of type `DateTime` and I am trying to figure out a method which returns `true` if the elements of the column `Term` are equal or their months and years are in sequence.

For Example, I have the following data for Term in the list AxiomData

```
   Term      CC
 dd/mm/yyyy
 10/10/2016  A
 10/9/2016   A
 10/8/2016   A
 10/7/2016   A
 10/6/2016   A
 16/5/2016   A
 10/4/2016   A
 10/3/2016   A
 10/2/2016   A
 10/1/2016   A
 10/12/2015  A
```

When the above List is passed to the function is passed to the method, it should return true as all the above in sequence from Dec-2015 to Oct-2016, it should also return true if the terms are equal.

I was able to do it for equal terms using the following code

```
if ((AxiomSubSet.Select(x => x.term).Distinct().ToList()).Count == 1)
{
//do something
}
```

Comment: what is the issue or concern?

Comment: Just want to figure a way to find if the terms are in sequence

Comment: Why don't you use a for loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Answer changed in response to comment. See below for original answer.)

So you just want to make sure that each date in the list is one month earlier than the previous one. Given a list of dates:

```
List<Date> dates;
```

If there aren't at least two dates in the list, then obviously it's in order. Assuming you have two or more dates:

```
for (var x = 1; x < dates.Count; ++x)
{
    var d1 = dates[x-1];
    var d2 = dates[x];
    // we need to ensure that d2 has a month/year
    // that is one month earlier than d1
    if (d2.Year > d1.Year) return false;
    if (d2.Year == d1.Year)
    {
        if ((d1.Month - d2.Month) != 1) return false;
        continue;
    }

    // At this point, d2.Year < d1.Year
    // In order to be valid, the difference must be 1,
    // and d1.Month must be 1 and d2.Month must be 12
    if ((d1.Year - d2-Year) != 1) return false;
    if (d1.Month != 1 || d2.Month != 12) return false;
}
return true;
```

### Original answer

If your example list is supposed to return `true`, then it looks like you're just trying to make sure that a list is in descending order. That last entry of 10/12/2015 shows that you don't want them to be only one day different.

That's pretty easy:

```
var Dates = new List<DateTime>();  // however you populate it
if (Dates.Count <= 1) return true;
for (var x = 1; x < Dates.Count; ++x)
{
    if (Dates[x] > Dates[x-1]) return false;
}
```

If only the months and years matter, just modify the test inside the loop:

```
    if (Dates[x].Year > Dates[x-1].Year) 
    {
        // current date is after previous date. List is out of order.
        return false;
    }
    if (Dates[x].Year < Dates[x-1].Year)
    {
        // current year is before previous year. This one is in order.
        continue;
    }
    if (Dates[x].Month > Dates[x-1].Month)
    {
        // Years are equal, but this date is after previous date.
        // List is out of order.
        return false;
    }
```

I really don't know if there's a LINQ way to do that.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion but my dates are in dd/mm/yyyy format

Comment: Everything seems to work fine but at if ((d1.Year - d2-Year) != 1) return false; if d1.year and d2.year are both 2016 as in my question it returns false and exits which may not be true all the time

Comment: @Dev: My mistake. I forgot to give it an early out when the years are equal. See the corrected code.

Answer (score 1):

You can start out with a simple method to pair off all of the items in a sequence with the item that comes before it:

```
public static IEnumerable<Tuple<T, T>> Pairwise<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    using (var iterator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!iterator.MoveNext())
            yield break;

        T prev = iterator.Current;

        while (iterator.MoveNext())
        {
            yield return Tuple.Create(prev, iterator.Current);
            prev = iterator.Current;
        }
    }
}
```

Once you can transform a sequence of items into a sequence of pairs of adjacent items you can assert that the sequence is increasing:

```
var isIncreasing = sequence.Pairwise()
    .All(pair => pair.Item1 >= pair.Item2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could compare your list to the same list sorted sequentially by date to see if they are already in sequence.

See [Enumerable.SequenceEqual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb348567%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Basically, create a copy of the list, sort it by date, and compare that to the original list using `.SequenceEqual`

Answer (score 0):

This will check if the dates in your list are sequential.In the loop its placed `<` to check is the date in an index is before the date in the previous index,because if equal sequential is still maintained:

```
bool AreDatesSequential = true;
for (int i = 1; i < AxiomSubSet.Count; i++)
{
     if (AxiomSubSet[i].Term < AxiomSubSet[i - 1].Term)
     {
         AreDatesSequential = false;
         break;
     }
}
```

We assume they are sequential,thats why `AreDatesSequential` is set to true and check in the loop for our assumption beeing wrong and if so the result will be false.

Comment: This is checking for ascending order. OP wants descending order and (apparently) a month/year difference of exactly 1 month.

Comment: @JimMischel yes it is and by what i read in OP question i also thought that but in is question he says "from Dec-2015 to Oct-2016" which made me go for ascending.